# Python parsing all functions with parameters from another file to console menu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a console menu for the user to do verification on a USB. I have a `verification.py` with all my verification functions that I am trying to call in `console_menu.py`. Currently, I am writing the functions into `console_menu.py` manually whenever there is a new function in `verification.py`.

verification.py:

```
def verify_mountpoint(mountpoint):
    ....
    ....

return True

def verify_filesystem(mountpoint):
    ....
    ....

return True   

def verify_size(mountpoint, usb_name):
    ....
    ....

return Size
```

console_menu.py:

```
def verification_menu(): 
menu_options = {   # is there a way to call ALL the functions in verification.py here?
    "verify_mountpoint": (verify_mountpoint, ["mountpoint"]), 
    "verify_filesystem": (verify_filesystem, ["mountpoint"]),
    "verify_size": (verify_size, ["mountpoint", "usb_name"])
}
...
...
```

My question is, is there a way to automatically grab all the functions in `verification.py` so I don't have to manually type each function in manually in `console_menu.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically grab **all** functions from a module is generally not a good idea.

It is dangerous, because modules usually have protected functions and functions that you have imported from other modules.

However, you can do what you want if you have some way to select only the desired functions from the module, either using some rule about their names or by checking their properties.

Here is an example using the name of the functions as a way to filter them.

```
import verification
from inspect import signature

# Obtain a list of all functions in `verify` which have `verify_` in their name
# `my_function` is a list of tuples (function_name, function)
my_functions = [(func_name, getattr(verification, func_name)) for func_name in dir(verification) if "verify_" in func_name] 

menu_options = {func_name: (func, list(signature(func).parameters)) for func_name, func in my_functions}
```

The `list(signature(func).parameters))` obtains a list of the arguments' names of the `func` function.